# Property access inside `onclick` attribute fails

Tags: javascript

This is not  working:

```
onclick="top.frames["topFrame"].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
```

But the following two are working

```
onclick="top.topFrame.document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
onclick="top.frames[0].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
```

But I know the first line is valid. Please tell me the right way.

Comment: Please note the syntax highlighting here

Comment: *i know the first line is valid*... obviously it is not.

Comment: Either it's Monday, or you need to brush up on your Javascrsipt syntax...

Comment: You shouldn't say `asap` to people your asking for help from.

Comment: @Marc B — HTML syntax ;)

Answer (score 4):

Replace the double quotes by simple quotes in the onclick attribute value:

```
onclick="top.frames['topFrame'].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="top.frames['topFrame'].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute is delimited by double quotes, so the use of a double quote in the script terminates the attribute value.

```
onclick="top.frames["
```

Either:

- Quote the attribute value using single quotes and all strings in JS with double quotes
- Quote the attribute value using double quotes and all strings in JS with single quotes
- Replace the double quotes in the attribute value with the entity reference: `&quot;`

Such:

```
onclick='top.frames["topFrame"].document.form1.text.value="hurray"'
onclick="top.frames['topFrame'].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
onclick="top.frames[&quot;topFrame&quot;].document.form1.text.value='hurray'"
```